# Fixed height div inside a table cell without extending the height of the cell

Tags: html, css

I have a table where the cells have a fixed height. Within the table I have a div which has a fixed height as well, and if that height exceeds the cell height, I would like it to overflow out of the cell, without the cell height extending (not a layout I would normally want to build, but it is a given start point at the moment).

For example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                12345
            </div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

table
{
     width: 90%;
     margin: 10px;   
}

td
{
    width: 50%;   
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

div
{
    height: 250px;
    width: 75%; 
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This resulted the table cell height to extend according to the div height.

I tried adding `position: absolute` to the div, and `position: absolute` to the td, and that did the trick in Chrome and IE (see this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JU9tn/3/)):

[image]

However, in Firefox the `position: absolute` caused the width of the div to relate to the window width instead of the cell width:

[image]

How can this be fixed? I'm looking for either a solution other than the `position: absolute`, or a way to get the div width right in FF.

Comment: May I ask why you're using tables for layout? I getting a headache just from looking at your question `:P`

Comment: I'm working on an existing page. I would not use such a layout in a new one, but at the moment changing it take too long (it is quite complex and ugly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you need using an extra div inside the table cell:

CSS:

```
table
{
     width: 90%;
     margin: 10px;   
}

tr
{
    height: 100px;
}
td
{
    width: 50%;   
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}

div.outer {
    height:100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100%;
}

div.inner
{
  height: 250px;
  width: 75%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="inner">
                    12345
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I forked your jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/dyes5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow:hidden` on the TD.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Tried it, no effect (cell is still stretching).

Comment: I don't think this is what he's looking for.  He needs to have it displayed outside the cell if needed.